# Should online renewals generate a Membership Renewal Activity? and how about when a Pay Later renewal is set to completed?

Tags: civimember, activities

Not sure if this is a regression, but currently (and since august at least) on civi 4.7.x when you renew online there is no Membership Renewal activity created.

I just tested this on d.46 where with a $0 membership the online renewal did create a Membership Renewal Activity.

Same thing on sandbox did not. Bug? Regression? Confused tester?

http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=207

A separate issue for both 4.6 and 4.7 seems to be that online Pay Later does not generate the Membership Renewal Activity when the payment is set to Completed.

Both of the above mean that searches based on that Activity Type as a way of figuring who renewed when do not work as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there was a regression. Jira ticket [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19600) (now FIXED) for the lack of Membership Renewal activity creation when you renew online that was fixed for 4.7.15.

Second ticket for [No Membership Renewal Activity is created when a Pay Later is set to Completed](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19678) not yet fixed

Comment: due to be fixed 4.7.15